# Only show a div if the modelstate has errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a div which contains a generic styling and error message if a user enters the wrong username/password combo.

I only want to display this div if the user has entered the wrong information. Is there something on my View I could do, something like:

```
@if(ModelState.HasErrors)
{
      <div>This login failed</div>
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
      <div>This login failed</div>
}
```

Side note, can't you use the built-in Validation helpers?

Controller:

```
if (yourError)
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "This login failed");
   return View();
}
```

View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that helped. Yes, usually I would use the built-in Validation Errors but for the app I'm currently developing I needed to follow a set style/rule that has already been set up for the login error.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff - no problems. But it's just that this way, your saying "If ANY error occured, show `this login failed` message". Which isn't really true.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the consequence of this, but it's instructions I've been told to follow so I can't really divert from it.